# Angular 2 assign a click function using a ternary operator

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to apply a click function:

```
setPage(page - 1)
```

But only if this condition matches:

```
page > 1
```

I thought I could do it like this but it didn't work, any ideas?

```
<a (click)="{'setPage(page - 1)' : page > 1}">Previous</a></li>
```

Comment: Have you tried giving the anchor it's own click method which handles this logic? It would be cleaner.

Comment: Just assign `onLinkClick(page)` to it and let the method handle it `if(page > 1) ...do something`

Comment: However if you are dead set on this mechanism it would be something like `(click)="page > 1 ? setPage(page - 1) : void"`, assuming that `setPage` has a void return.

Comment: @cyrix That method would mean that the `setPage` method is coupled to the anchor - it's likely that other things will call this method and the `page > 1` logic will not be applicable.

Comment: It did mean the same as you ;) just forgot to change the method name.

Comment: @cyrix Ah good shout - that's the ideal solution, go ahead and make it an answer.

Comment: Maybe you could use two <a> and use ng-show. The first <a> would be shown when page >1 and use the setPage on click. The second would be shown when page <-1 and not bind to the setPage. But i would rather prefer cyrix sugestion.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I've gone with @echonax answer because I ideally wanted to keep the logical in the html in this particular scenerio rather than putting it in the method. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work:

```
<a (click)="page > 1 ? setPage(page - 1) : null">Previous</a></li>
```

similar example: http://plnkr.co/edit/ojO0GwQktneBuzKqKTwz?p=preview

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments:

Create a new method in your component called for example `onAnchorClick` and let it handle the logic.

```
public onAnchorClick(page: number) {
   if(page > 1) {
     this.setPage(page - 1);
     // some other stuff to do
   }
}
```

and bind it to your Anchor

```
<a (click)="onAnchorClick(page)">Previous</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. I went ahead with Echonax answer because I have many other operators going on in the same page and preferred keeping the logic there rather than having some logic in the html file ans some logic in the method. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
<a (click)="page > 1 ? setPage(page - 1) : null">Previous</a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Rahul. Echonax got in there just a few seconds before you but still thanks for your help. :)